# memorize multiple outputs in a string array

Tags: c, arrays, pipe

I need to get different information regarding the times a `character` was send from the parent process to the `child` process. Each second I shall have an `array` that stores the amount of times that particular character was received.

However my problem is that I don't know how to send all this information to a pipe back to the parent process as a reply.

What i'm trying to do is :

```
char caracter;
int number;

while((number = read(pipe1[0], &character, 1) > 0)) 
    stats[position] += number;  
close(pipe1[0]);
```

Now i need to send the values in :

```
stats[0]+stats[1]+stats[2]+stats[3]+stats[4],stats[0],stats[1],stats[2],stats[3],stats[4]
```

to `pipe2`.

I want to send it via :

```
write(pipe2[1], [stats values] ,strlen([stats values]));
```

I don't know how to memorize everything in a single `array` and then to be able to still print separately the number of times a character was read by second. I must mention that it is impossible for me to know beforehand how long will this array be.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure pipes is the correct approach here? Maybe you can just create some shared memory to hold the `stat` array and the parent and child both will have access to it. Parent can calculate whatever function it wants on it.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm required to use pipes for this matter...

Comment: What kind of values are stored in `stats`? Ints? longs? chars?

Comment: They are int values

Comment: One solution: loop over the array and send one entry at a time with `write()`.

Comment: This seems like back to basics, but what type of characters are you trying to send from parent to child ?

Comment: Parent sends just an 'a' character, for example, to the child

Answer (score 0):

One idea here is if you want an array that can hold an amount of values you don't know ahead of time, you can use a simple expandable buffer implementation.

Here, `Buf` is a struct that uses a len and cap field to determine the amount of space left in the buffer, before it needs to make a call to `realloc` and expand to add more space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// C dynamic buffer

//checks if buffer is full.
#define Buf_FULL(buf) (buf->len == buf->cap)

// Macro to expand buffer.
#define Buf_EXPAND(buf, amount) \
        buf->cap += amount; \
        buf = realloc(buf, sizeof(Buf) + buf->cap)


typedef struct
{
  size_t len;
  size_t cap;
  int data[0];
} Buf;

Buf* Buf_new(size_t capacity)
{
  Buf* newb = malloc(sizeof(Buf) + capacity);
  newb->len = 0;
  newb->cap = capacity;
  return newb;
}

void Buf_write(Buf* buf, int num)
{
  if(Buf_FULL(buf)) Buf_EXPAND(buf, 10);
  buf->data[buf->len++] = num;
}

int main(void)
{
  Buf* foo = Buf_new(10);
  Buf_write(foo, 50);
  Buf_write(foo, 10);
  return 0;
}
```

You can then read the int values via accessing `b->data[i]`, as you would a normal array. The field `int data[0];` is a dummy pointer which allows the array to access any size that is passed to `malloc`. Meaning you can use heap memory to construct on array of whatever starting size you choose.

*Note*: You also need to free the buffer with `free` when you are done using it.